# I don't know what this exception is?

Tags: spring-mvc

This is my Dispatcher codes

```
@RequestMapping(value="blogWrite", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView writeBlog(BlogText blogText, MultipartFile[] files, HttpSession session) {
    System.out.println("writeBlog() 실행");
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("/Blog/BlogPersonal/blogPersonal");
    MemberInfo memberInfo = (MemberInfo)session.getAttribute("session");

    final String path = "C:/Users/Dongjoo/Downloads/fileUpload/"+memberInfo.getMemberId();

    logger.info("path:{}",path);

    blogService.addBlogText(modelAndView,blogText,files,path);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

And this is my service layer codes

```
@Autowired
private BlogDAO blogDAO;

public MemberInfo getMemberLogin(MemberInfo memberInfo) {       
    MemberInfo takeMemberInfo = blogDAO.memberLogin(memberInfo);
    return takeMemberInfo;
}
public ModelAndView addBlogText(ModelAndView modelAndView, BlogText blogText, MultipartFile[] files, final String path) {
    System.out.println("addBlogText() 실행");
    for(MultipartFile file : files){
        File newFile = new File(path+"/"+file.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(newFile, file.getBytes());
            System.out.println("파일 업로드 성공!");
            modelAndView.addObject("message", "파일업로드 성공!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("파일 업로드 실패!");
            modelAndView.addObject("message", "파일업로드 실패!");
        }           
    }
    return modelAndView;
}
```

And web.xml

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
    </param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
  <display-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</display-name>
  <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <description></description>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
```

And pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

And writeForm.jsp

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var day = 1;
            $('#addBtn').click(function() {
                var tagAdd = '';
                console.log('일차 : '+day);

                if(day==1) {
                    tagAdd += '<div class="dayAndTimeDiv">';
                        tagAdd += '<input type="hidden" class="dayRequired" name="dayRequired" value="'+day+'"/>';
                        tagAdd += '<span class="dayRequiredShow">'+day+'일차</span>';
                        tagAdd += '<input type="text"  class="timeRequired" name="timeRequired" size="2"/>';
                        tagAdd += '<span class="timeRequiredDiv"> 시간</span>';
                        tagAdd += '</div>';
                    tagAdd += '<div class="imageArea">';
                        tagAdd += '<input type="file" id="blogTextImage" name="blogTextImage"/><br/>';
                        tagAdd += '<textarea rows="20" cols="50" id="blogTextContent" name="blogTextContent"></textarea>';
                    tagAdd += '</div>';
                    $('#writeArea').append(tagAdd);
                    console.log(tagAdd);
                }
                else {
                    /* 지금 태그 추가/삭제가 안 된다. 일단 이것은 나중으로 미루고... */
                    $('#addBtnDiv').remove();
                    tagAdd = '<input type="button" id="addBtn"/>';
                    $('#addBtnDiv').append(tagAdd);
                    tagAdd = '';
                    tagAdd += '<div class="dayAndTimeDiv">';
                    tagAdd += '<input type="hidden" class="dayRequired" name="dayRequired" value="'+day+'"/>';
                    tagAdd += '<span class="dayRequiredShow">'+day+'일차</span>';
                    tagAdd += '<input type="text"  class="timeRequired" name="timeRequired" size="2"/>';
                    tagAdd += '<span class="timeRequiredDiv"> 시간</span>';
                    tagAdd += '</div>';
                    tagAdd += '<div class="imageArea">';
                        tagAdd += '<input type="file" id="blogTextImage" name="blogTextImage" multiple="multiple"/><br/>';
                        tagAdd += '<textarea rows="20" cols="50" id="blogTextContent" name="blogTextContent"></textarea>';
                    tagAdd += '</div>';                 
                    $('#writeArea').append(tagAdd);
                    console.log(tagAdd);
                }
                day++;
            });
            $('#insertBlogTextBtn').click(function() {
                $('form').submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="memberNameDiv">
        <span id="memberName">${session.memberName}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <hr>
    </div>
<div id="blogTextArea">
    <form action="/blogWrite" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="categoryDiv">
            <span id="categoryHover">카테고리</span>
        </div>
        <div id="addBtnDiv">
            <input type="button" id="addBtn"/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="writeArea">


        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="buttonArea">
    <input type="button" id="insertBlogTextBtn" name="insertBlogTextBtn" value="글등록"/>
    <input type="reset" id="cancelBtn" name="cancelBtn" value="취소"/>
</div>
```

I didn't make DAO part yet for putting data in database

I want to put some files.

But i've got Exception(error)

below :

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [[Lorg.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Lorg.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;.<init>()] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Lorg.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/wpad.dat] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/wpad.dat] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/wpad.dat] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/wpad.dat] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/wpad.dat] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/wpad.dat] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/wpad.dat] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/wpad.dat] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/wpad.dat] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/wpad.dat] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

please help me!!!(please Ignore Korean language what i wrote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare CommonsMultipartResolver bean in serlvet configuration.

eg.

```
For XML config:
--------------
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize">
        <value>2097152</value> <!-- 2MB -->
    </property>
</bean>

For java config:
---------------
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
}


In Controller annotation use like :
@RequestParam("photo") MultipartFile file
```

Comment: Thank you, I found way out differently